# Adding new customers in a dataframe after calculating their loyalty value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset df which includes information on old customers and a list of customers that may be new or old. I would like to assign a loyalty value to new customers, i.e. those customers not evaluated yet in the dataset df.
Please see below an example of what I would like to achieve.
Let's say that I have a list of potential new customers (e.g., `customers=['cust1', 'cust76']`) whose information on their loyalty might be missing in the df dataset (called here `existing_cust_df`).

```
existing_cust_df=pd.read(path.csv)
```

The dataset has only two fields: one refers to customer's ID and the other one refers to the loyalty values (called just `value`).

```
Customer         value 
cust2             13
cust3             14
cust6             35
cust7             21
cust1             24
```

I would like to determine the loyalty of the new customer(s) (in this example will be only `cust76`, as `cust1` is already in the dataset and we have information on its value - ie. 24) based on the value of existing customers included in the `existing_cust_df` dataset.

To determine the value of new customers, I use a distinct dataset, called `extra_df`, which includes the new customer and a list of potential customers that might be used to determine its loyalty value. The `extra_df` dataset looks like as follows:

```
   Customer         Related_customer
    cust76             cust32
    cust76             cust2
    cust76             cust1
```

The extra_df can then be used to look at related customers that might be included in the `existing_cust_df` in order to get their values from there and assign to the new customer by averaging those values.
In the example I provided, `cust76` is missing in the `existing_cust_df` so I look at the `extra_df` where, out of three customers related to it, there are only two (`cust2` and `cust1`) that are in the `existing_cust_df` so their values.
By averaging their values (`13` and `24`), I would like to assign this value (`18.5`) to the new customer (`cust76`) and append its ID (`cust76`) and its calculated value (`18.5`) to the `existing_cust_df`.
So at the end I would have:

```
Customer         value 
cust2             13
cust3             14
cust6             35
cust7             21
cust1             24
cust76            18.5
```

I hope the steps above make sense; if they do not, please let me know.
Can you please tell me how to run this check, looking at a customer in the list into the `existing_cust_df`, then in the `extra_df` if not included, calculating its average and finally update the value in the `existing_cust_df`?
I know that to append a row in an existing dataframe I should do:

```
new_row = {'Customer': cust76, 'value': 18.5}
#append row to the dataframe
existing_cust_df = existing_cust_df.append(new_row, ignore_index=False)
```

But the difficulties in this case are to look at customers in the list that are not in the `existing_cust_df` and, then, at `extra_df`, in order to include them and their values once calculated the average (otherwise, it would be also good to assign a null value).

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first build our dataframes :

```py
csvfile = StringIO(
"""Customer\tvalue
cust2\t13
cust3\t14
cust6\t35
cust7\t21
cust1\t24""")
existing_cust_df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = '\t', engine='python')

csvfile = StringIO("""
Customer\tRelated_customer
cust76\tcust32
cust76\tcust2
cust76\tcust1""")
extra_df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = '\t', engine='python')
```

We want to loop for each input in `extra_df`, let's groupby :

```py
dg = extra_df.groupby('Customer')
```

Then we can build a mask for each customer in extra_cust_df : `True` if a related_customer is in existing_cust_df.

```py
dg.Related_customer.apply(lambda x : existing_cust_df.Customer.isin(x.to_numpy()))
Out[123]: 
Customer   
cust76    0     True
          1    False
          2    False
          3    False
          4     True
Name: Related_customer, dtype: bool
```

We can then apply this mask on existing_cust_df.value and then average it :

```py
dg.Related_customer.apply(lambda x : existing_cust_df.query("Customer.isin(@x.to_numpy())"))

Out[125]: 
           Customer  value
Customer                  
cust76   0    cust2     13
         4    cust1     24


dg.Related_customer.apply(lambda x : existing_cust_df.query("Customer.isin(@x.to_numpy())").value.mean())

Out[126]: 
Customer
cust76    18.5
Name: Related_customer, dtype: float64
```

Finally we can append it to your existing df

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do what your question asks:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Objective:
#    for each customer in customers not already in existing_cust_df, 
#    add a record to existing_cust_df with value equal to 
#    the average of the values from existing_cust_df 
#    of Related_customer records in extra_df 
#    where extra_df.Customer == customer and Related_customer is in existing_cust_df.

existing_cust_df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer':['cust2','cust3','cust6','cust7','cust1'], 'value':[13,14,35,21,24]})
print("existing_cust_df:")
print(existing_cust_df)

extra_df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer':['cust76','cust76','cust76', 'cust77', 'cust77'], 'Related_customer':['cust32','cust2','cust1', 'cust2', 'cust6']})
print("extra_df:")
print(extra_df)

customers=['cust1', 'cust76', 'cust77']
new_cust_df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer': [c for c in customers if c not in set(existing_cust_df['Customer'])]})
print("new_cust_df:")
print(new_cust_df)

# create a record for each new_cust containing list of related_cust names 
#    with matching customer in extra_df where related_cust is a customer in existing_cust_df
existing_related_customer_values = \
    pd.merge( \
        pd.merge(extra_df, new_cust_df, on= 'Customer'), \
        existing_cust_df, left_on='Related_customer', right_on='Customer', suffixes=(None, '_y')) \
    [['Customer', 'Related_customer', 'value']]
print("existing_related_customer_values\n (JOIN from new_cust_df and extra_df on Customer [KEEP],\n then JOIN on extra_df.Related_customer and existing_cust_df.Customer [KEEP value])")
print(existing_related_customer_values)

# find the mean of values for existing Related_customer records for new customers
new_cust_df['value'] = new_cust_df.apply(lambda x: np.mean( \
    existing_related_customer_values[existing_related_customer_values['Customer'] == x['Customer']]['value']), axis=1)
print("new_cust_df (UPDATED with value column):")
print(new_cust_df)

existing_cust_df = pd.concat([existing_cust_df, new_cust_df], ignore_index=True)
print("existing_cust_df (UPDATED with new customer rows):")
print(existing_cust_df)
```

Output:

```
existing_cust_df:
  Customer  value
0    cust2     13
1    cust3     14
2    cust6     35
3    cust7     21
4    cust1     24
extra_df:
  Customer Related_customer
0   cust76           cust32
1   cust76            cust2
2   cust76            cust1
3   cust77            cust2
4   cust77            cust6
new_cust_df:
  Customer
0   cust76
1   cust77
existing_related_customer_values
 (JOIN from new_cust_df and extra_df on Customer [KEEP],
 then JOIN on extra_df.Related_customer and existing_cust_df.Customer [KEEP value])
  Customer Related_customer  value
0   cust76            cust2     13
1   cust77            cust2     13
2   cust76            cust1     24
3   cust77            cust6     35
new_cust_df (UPDATED with value column):
  Customer  value
0   cust76   18.5
1   cust77   24.0
existing_cust_df (UPDATED with new customer rows):
  Customer  value
0    cust2   13.0
1    cust3   14.0
2    cust6   35.0
3    cust7   21.0
4    cust1   24.0
5   cust76   18.5
6   cust77   24.0
```